# What does そういうことだよ mean here?

Tags: grammar, meaning, spoken-language

> 「これからね。パパと映画を観にいくの！そのあとね、カフェでフルーツパフェ食べるんだよ！」
>
> 言ったあぁ〜。言ってしまったぁ〜。
>
> 「そうか〜。それはよかったね〜」
>
> その子のお父さんがそう言いました。
>
> 「◯◯ちゃんは、どこに行ってたの？」
>
> 音ちゃんが聞いています。全然空気を読んでない。
>
> 「お腹まだ治らないから病院に行ってきたんだよ」
>
> また、お父さんが答えました。
>
> その瞬間、音ちゃんはハッとした表情をして、わたしのほうを見たのです。
>
> 「じゃあ、さようなら〜」
>
> そう言って、音ちゃんは走ってわたしのところに戻ってきました。
>
> わたし「わかった？」
>
> 音「うん…」
>
> わたし「あれはよくなかったね。急性胃腸炎で休んでいること忘れてたの？」
>
> 音「うん。忘れてた」
>
> わたし「**そういうことだよ**。音ちゃん。自慢しちゃダメだって意味、わかった？」
>
> 音「うん。反省した。自分がイヤになっちゃう。もう自慢しない」

---

> 「押し倒されちゃって、脱がされちゃって……求められちゃった」
> 「**そういうことだよ**。ずっと俺の腕を挟んでくれちゃってたんだから……」

In the two parts above I am lost as to what そういうこと means and is doing.

From the internet the meanings of そういうこと that I can find are:

> 前述の発言全体を指す表現。「そういう事は早く言え」などのように用いられる
>
> 前述の発言内容を全面的に肯定する意味合いでも用いられる。この場合は感動詞的な機能を持つ。

The first meaning doesn't seem like it matches up with the usages above. However, the second meaning doesn't really make sense to me in context. Is there another usage for そういうこと that I am missing or can someone explain the usage more clearly?

Answer (score 2):

そういうこと in the first dialog corresponds to the second meaning: 「前述の発言内容を全面的に肯定する」. This そういうこと refers to the "lesson" which 音ちゃん just realized (自慢しちゃダメ). This kind of そういうこと can be translated as "Now you understand it", "Yeah, that's what I mean", etc.

(Strictly speaking, in this case, 音ちゃん had not explicitly said something like 自慢しちゃダメだった when he said そういうことだよ, so there was no 発言 which そういうこと directly refers to. But he knew she learned the important lesson from her facial expression, so he said そういうことだよ.)

I can't tell what そういうこと specifically means in the second dialog. It needs more context.